# Blur validation gets triggered before input selection fills the data field - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, ecmascript-6, onblur

Following is my country selector drop down which pops in as soon as user Focus the input field. I have made a validation `onBlur` as data cannot be remains empty in the input field. Problem is on selecting the value from the list `onBlur` fires immediately and then the values gets populated in the dropdown which is causing `onBlur` validation message to appear on screen.

Let me know how can I manage the situation by removing the `onBlur` validation once user selects the value from the list.

React Code -

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      blurText: "Field Cannot be left blank",
      listData: [],
      selectedValue: "",
      showList: false,
      showBlurText: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      listData: [
        { id: 1, name: "Australia" },
        { id: 2, name: "Germany" },
        { id: 3, name: "France" }
      ]
    });
  }

  handleBlur = e => {
    if (!e.target.innerHTML) {
      this.setState({
        showBlurText: true
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        showBlurText: false
      });
    }
  };

  showDataList = () => {
    this.setState({
      showList: true
    });
  };

  handleSelection = e => {
    this.setState({
      selectedValue: e.target.innerHTML
    });
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ selectedValue: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h3>Test Select</h3>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="autosuggest"
          value={this.state.selectedValue}
          onFocus={this.showDataList}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        {this.state.showList && (
          <ul>
            {this.state.listData.map(x => {
              return (
                <li key={x.id} onClick={this.handleSelection}>
                  {x.name}
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        )}
        <hr />
        {this.state.showBlurText && (
          <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{this.state.blurText}</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Working Codesandbox with the scenario - https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-brook-h7kin

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, you can check on this link:
[Codesandbox: Click catcher on blur](https://codesandbox.io/s/click-catcher-on-blur-uuml2)

The issue is you put the **onBlur** prop to the **input element,** so when you click an item in the **ul element**, the **onBlur** gets triggered.

So what I did is to create a simple click-catcher so when you click outside of input or ul, it will be triggered.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using onBlur you can check validations on onChange event, check the working [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-on-blur-issue-tuuiq)

some tips below that will make your code clean:

Instead of using if-else while validating emptyefields you can directly use !(negate operator) in your handleBlur function.

```
  handleBlur = e => {
    this.setState({
       showBlurText: !e.target.innerHTML
    })
  }
```